# Tablesorter ordering dates and empty dates incorrectly

Tags: date, tablesorter

My tablesorter table is not sorting dates and empty fields correctly.

I would expect empty fields to be treated like zeros, and be grouped at the top/bottom. Instead I get some dates beneath them.

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    widthFixed: true,
    // sort on the last name in ascending order
    sortList: [
        [2, 0]
    ],
    dateFormat: "ddmmyyyy",
    emptyTo: "zero",
    sortInitialOrder: "desc",
    headers: {
        3: {
            sorter: "shortDate"
        },
        4: {
            sorter: "shortDate"
        },
        5: {
            sorter: "shortDate"
        },
        6: {
            sorter: "shortDate"
        }
    },
    textExtraction: {
        3: function (n, t, c) {
            return $(n).attr('data-date');
        },
        4: function (n, t, c) {
            return $(n).attr('data-date');
        },
        5: function (n, t, c) {
            return $(n).attr('data-date');
        }
    },
    widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']
});
```

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5UZ7M/2/). Sort using the 'Date of birth' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "shortDate" parser converts all dates into a time in milliseconds to make date comparison (using a operator or date range with the filter widget) and sorting of dates easier. In order to do that, it uses a javascript function [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

> The value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

So, the issue you are noticing is because non-date cells are treated as having a zero-value, and the date that is not sorting properly is the date "1/1/1930". Entering this date into the javascript console, you'll see this result:

```
new Date('1/1/1930').getTime()
// returns -1262282400000
```

Remember, it's the time since 1/1/1970, so the time returns a negative number, which of course is less than zero.

The simplest solution would be to just set the `emptyTo` option to `"min"`, which sets the value of any empty cells to be a maximum negative number ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/5UZ7M/4/)):

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I just noticed something odd though: when I sort ascending I'd expect the 'not sets' to be at the top of the list -- instead they're at the bottom. Sort-descending behaves in the opposite manner. If change `emptyTo` to `"max"` it behaves in the expected manner :)